# Accessing to Asp.net Session data using SessionID

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm doing a pretty weird trick to use asp.net inside a php page in cross-domain. I had lot of problem but i someway solved all. Now the last problem:

i need to read asp.net Session data having the SessionID only.

i already tried what suggested from the author of swfupload here: http://web.archive.org/web/20120415034411/http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/98

thats reduces in this:

```
Dim cookie As HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("ASP.NET_SessionId")
cookie.Value = "mySessionID"
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Set(cookie)
```

but if i check the Session.SessionID after this i still got the old session value. 
I Read i should use "Response" to set cookies on the client, but it doesn't work even with this:

```
Response.Cookies("ASP.NET_SessionId").Value = "mySessionID"
```

Still got the same SessionID after this.

SessionID is read only and i can't overwrite it with a normal Session.SessionID = "myid"

I tried (and failed) even with this:

```
Dim ctx = HttpContext.Current
ctx.Response.Cookies.Remove("ASP.NET_SessionId")
ctx.Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "mySessionID"))
```

How can i do this?

**Edit**: i add another failure test

```
Dim a, b As Boolean
Dim SM As New SessionIDManager
SM.InitializeRequest(HttpContext.Current, False, True)
SM.RemoveSessionID(HttpContext.Current)
SM.SaveSessionID(HttpContext.Current, "mySessionID", a, b)
```